# Google Cloud logging, sending slack notifications only for newly appeared errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

need to send alerts to slack using google cloud logging but send the alert only once, because the alert may be repeated multiple times and this will cause a lot of miss.

Answer (score 0):

If in addition to the filter for the `log based metric`, you added `labels` with extractors, the alert is fired multiple times.

The metric is checked for each labels and not once.

Check if in your case, you added labels with extractors.

[image]

In my example I added a `log based metric` with a filter for some error types in `Cloud Composer`. In order to increment my metric and make be unique, I also added labels on the current `Airflow` `task id` and `execution date`.

Then I just need to create an alerting policy on this log based metric with a treshold.

If I don't add labels and extractor, my alert is fired only once.